# PowerApps: OnVisible CountRows in child gallery control?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I made a PowerApps form for SharePoint and wanted to capture a count of items listed in a gallery control. The gallery is child to the main form parent. I set my Count function to fire when Screen.OnVisible, but I think this fires before the gallery is loaded because my X variable returned is always 0.

Suggestions?

```
ScreenView.OnVisible = Set(X, CountRows(Tasks))
```

Comment: I've just replicated the same thing, and I also had 0 in a preview mode. But as soon as I've published it and looked at the results as a normal user I could see that variable shows the correct number. Did you try to publish your app?

Comment: Yeah, published, no go. But, might be my form, has been degrading somehow. I'm flushing all the code and hoping not to have to redo, formatting takes forevvvvvver...

Comment: I just had the same thing. Now my sample does not work even though it worked an hour ago. Now it does not show the numbers. So strange.

Comment: I’m thinking OnVisible is just that; on visible, not to be confused with on loaded, which would be very handy.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a support case on this. They said don't do that in the onVisible of the screen. Do it in the OnEdit or  OnNew event ove the SharePoint connection object.

Does that work for you?

Comment: Not really, unless I’m missing the concept. Am thinking more like javascript load event in general; something fires when a resource and its dependent resources have finished loading.